# Travelling Salesman with minimum change permutation

Tags: algorithm, permutation, traveling-salesman

I am reading about permutation generation and relationship with Travelling Salesman Problem in [Introduction to design and analysis of algorithms](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=mXA_r6mb-s8C&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=travel%20salesman%20problem%20with%20minimal%20change%20permutation&source=bl&ots=hMcZ-T3q1X&sig=YauviCe3Liat7cQDXqSdsKfc-lU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yHSvVJHtGImjugTr7IDQDw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=travel%20salesman%20problem%20with%20minimal%20change%20permutation&f=false).

Here author mentioned as below

> We can insert n in the previously generated permutations either left
>   to right or right to left. It turns out that it is beneficial to start
>   with inserting n into 12 . . . (n − 1) by moving right to left and
>   then switch direction every time a new permutation of {1, . . . , n −
>   1} needs to be processed. The advantage of this order of generating
>   permutations stems from the fact that it satisfies the minimal-change
>   requirement: each permutation can be obtained from its immediate
>   predecessor by exchanging just two elements in it.
>
> If such permutations are generated by a minimal-change algorithm, we
>   can compute the length of a new tour from the length of its
>   predecessor in constant rather than linear time.

My question on above text: How can we calculate length form predecessor in constant time if we use minimum change algorithm? If possible, please give a simple example with `n=3`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you swap element b with element e, oddly chosen letters because we suppose b is the middle element of a path a->b->c and e is the middle element of a path d->e->f.

4 edges disappear, they are replaced by 4 new edges. The ones that disappear are the ones that connect b and e to their old neighbours. The new ones are a->e, e->c, d->b and b->f.

So the new total length is

```
old - d(a, b) - d(b, c) - d(d, e) - d(e, f) + d(a, e) + d(e, c) + d(d, b) + d(b, f)
```

Comment: can you please eloborate. Not able to follow above explanation. Thanks

Comment: @venkysmarty ok but is there anything in particular you don't follow about it?

Comment: To put it differently - the change in cost is only local. The change of cost can be calculated given the graph only; if the current cost of a tour is known, this change cost can be added to obtain the cost of a new tour.

Comment: @ harold: how we are using previous permutation and achieving constant time

Comment: @venkysmarty the previous path has a->b->c and d->e->f in it. The new path has b and e swapped, so it has a->e->c and d->b->f in it. The calculation I showed calculates the new length from the old length, and it is obviously a constant time calculation.